# Oracle NUMBER(p) storage size?

Tags: oracle, numbers, size, storage

I've searched for it but i can't find a conclusive answer to my question...

I need to know what is the storage size of a number(p) field in Oracle.

Examples: NUMBER(1), NUMBER(3), NUMBER(8), NUMBER(10) etc...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The storage used depends on the actual numeric value, as well as the column precision and scale of the column.

The [Oracle 11gR2 concepts guide says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT313):

> Oracle Database stores numeric data in variable-length format. Each value is stored in scientific notation, with 1 byte used to store the exponent. The database uses up to 20 bytes to store the mantissa, which is the part of a floating-point number that contains its significant digits. Oracle Database does not store leading and trailing zeros.

The [10gR2 guide goes further](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306%5F01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#sthref3818):

> Taking this into account, the column size in bytes for a particular
>   numeric data value NUMBER(p), where p is the precision of a given
>   value, can be calculated using the following formula:
>
> ```
> ROUND((length(p)+s)/2))+1
> ```
>
> where s equals zero if the number is positive, and s equals 1 if the
>   number is negative.
>
> Zero and positive and negative infinity (only generated on import from
>   Version 5 Oracle databases) are stored using unique representations.
>   Zero and negative infinity each require 1 byte; positive infinity
>   requires 2 bytes.

If you have access to My Oracle Support, there is more information in note 1031902.6.

[You can see the actual storage used with `vsize` or `dump`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1feaa/1).

```
create table t42 (n number(10));

insert into t42 values (0);
insert into t42 values (1);
insert into t42 values (-1);
insert into t42 values (100);
insert into t42 values (999);
insert into t42 values (65535);
insert into t42 values (1234567890);

select n, vsize(n), dump(n)
from t42
order by n;

          N   VSIZE(N)                           DUMP(N) 
------------ ---------- ---------------------------------
         -1          3           Typ=2 Len=3: 62,100,102 
          0          1                  Typ=2 Len=1: 128 
          1          2                Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2 
        100          2                Typ=2 Len=2: 194,2 
        999          3           Typ=2 Len=3: 194,10,100 
      65535          4          Typ=2 Len=4: 195,7,56,36 
 1234567890          6   Typ=2 Len=6: 197,13,35,57,79,91
```

Notice that the storage varies depending on the value, even though they are all in a `number(10)` column, and that two 3-digit numbers can need different amounts of storage.

Comment: +1 Thanks for introducing me to the `dump` function! Helps me in debugging some weird Oracle (client library) bug.

Comment: Old topic but... is there a similar question for Sql Server DECIMAL and NUMERIC type ?

Answer (score 1):

```
NUMBER  
999...(38 9's) x10125 
maximum value   Can be represented to full 38-digit precision (the mantissa).

-999...(38 9's) x10125 
minimum value   Can be represented to full 38-digit precision (the mantissa).


Precision   38 significant digits    ==> NUMBER(38) is the max
```

Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits001.htm) and also may be [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313)

Comment: thanks for the answer. But how can I calculate how many bytes does a three digit number occupies?

Answer (score 1):

The `number` data type in Oracle is a special data type that is variable length like `varchar`. Then if you store the same data in `number(5)` and `number(20)` the storage is the same like declaring a column as `varchar(100)` and `varchar(200)`.

So specifying the p parameter in `number(p,s)` has no effect on storage size and is only for applying constraint on the data. But specifying the s parameter can reduce the size by rounding the data.

the minimum storage size of number data type is 1 byte and the maximum is 21 bytes. So if you do not want to apply constraint then use `number` data type without p parameter.