# Is the memory reserved for a column in Oracle while creating table?

Tags: oracle, memory

Example :

```
create table sample-name
{
   sample-col-name number(1);
}
```

If we see the above example. when the table is created the sample-col-name column is created. By default it takes 22 bytes as it holds number datatype. But oracle dynamically gives the memory on the value that we are inserting. Say if we are entering 1 value then only 1 byte is given.
My question is are those 22 bytes preserved ? So, if 1 Byte is allocated out of 22 bytes, then other 21 bytes are unused ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really mean "memory" or do you mean "storage" (usually on hard disk?) The two are not the same - and the answer may or may not be the same for both.

Comment: Not sure why you refer to the point the table is created, but later refer to inserts; if you actually mean at insert time (which makes slightly more sense), [does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24240516/266304)?

Comment: Also note that Oracle doesn't use curly braces for (almost?) anything. The table definition should be enclosed in `( ... )` rather than `{ ... }`.

Comment: Sorry about the curly braces. I know it is enclosed in (...) braces.
And about the memory or storage, my concern is when we see all_tab_columns  of a table the data_length column says how many bytes it stores, for a number it shows 22(bytes) So, I'm not sure under which category it falls, if it is memory or storage.

Comment: It seems you're interested in storage rather than memory. Does the old answer I linked to explain it for you?

Comment: @AlexPoole. when we insert 1 byte is allocated if we insert value 1, so what happens to the rest of the 21 bytes? is it clear or is there still a confusion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be asking if 22 bytes of storage are consumed by a number value even if it doesn't require all of those bytes to store it. [A non-zero single-digit number requires two bytes of storage.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24240516/266304), and as the docs say they are stored in a variable-length format.

If all 22 bytes were consumed then 20 bytes would be wasted for every number you store.

You can test to see that is not happening.

```
create table t42 (n number(1));
column data_type format a10
select data_type, data_length from user_tab_columns where table_name = 'T42';

DATA_TYPE  DATA_LENGTH
---------- -----------
NUMBER              22
```

The table initially has no storage allocated (deferred segment creation), but as soon as a row is added a segment is allocated; 64k in this example:

```
select extents, bytes from user_segments where segment_name = 'T42';

no rows selected

insert into t42 select 1 from dual;

1 row inserted.

select extents, blocks, bytes from user_segments where segment_name = 'T42';

   EXTENTS     BLOCKS      BYTES
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          8      65536
```

And you can see the storage required for that value with `vsize` or `dump`, as mentioned in the linked answer:

```
select n, vsize(n), dump(n) from t42;

         N   VSIZE(N) DUMP(N)             
---------- ---------- --------------------
         1          2 Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2
```

If the table had 32768 (32k) rows, each with that same single digit value, then it would either need 65536 (64k) of storage at two bytes each, or 720896 (
704k) of storage at 22 bytes each. Just for that column without any row overhead (*at least* [3 bytes per row](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/logical.htm#CNCPT-GUID-D993A749-93D0-448C-BDC8-330D805AC481)) or block overhead (~84-107 bytes per block).

```
insert into t42 select 1 from dual connect by level < 3300;

3,299 rows inserted.

         N   COUNT(*) SUM(VSIZE(N))
---------- ---------- -------------
         1       3300          6600

select extents, blocks, bytes from user_segments where segment_name = 'T42';

   EXTENTS     BLOCKS      BYTES
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          8      65536
```

All 3300 rows still fit into a single 64k extent. If they were actually using 22 bytes per number then just those would already need 72500 bytes, and another extent would have had to be added already.

---

I didn't choose 3300 rows randomly; on my system one more row does push me into a second extent:

```
insert into t42 select 1 from dual;

1 row inserted.

select n, count(*), sum(vsize(n)) from t42 group by n;

         N   COUNT(*) SUM(VSIZE(N))
---------- ---------- -------------
         1       3301          6602

    select extents, blocks, bytes from user_segments where segment_name = 'T42';

   EXTENTS     BLOCKS      BYTES
---------- ---------- ----------
         2         16     131072
```

so there's quite a bit of block and row overhead involved. You can a sense of how much with a table with more columns:

```
drop table t42;
create table t42 (n1 number, n2 number, n3 number, n4 number, n5 number); 
insert into t42 select 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 from dual connect by level <= 1815;
select count(*), sum(vsize(n1) + vsize(n1) + vsize(n1) + vsize(n1) + vsize(n1)) as total_vsize from t42;

  COUNT(*) TOTAL_VSIZE
---------- -----------
      1815       18150

select extents, blocks, bytes from user_segments where segment_name = 'T42';

   EXTENTS     BLOCKS      BYTES
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          8      65536
```

Again adding one more row requires a second extent. But now if we had 1815 rows, each with five single-numbers, then if each of those was using 22 bytes we would need 199650 bytes, and clearly we aren't actually using that. The row overhead is just less significant compared to the number storage with more rows now that there are more columns, as you would expect. But in this still-contrived example we're still only getting about 18k of actual data in a 64k extent; better than the earlier example with a single column which only got 6k though...

Try it yourself with your configuration and more columns, and/or columns with different data types (`varchar2` behaves in a similar way).