# Not getting PLW-07203 for numbers

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have started using compiler warnings for my PL/SQL code and I do not understand why I am getting PLW-07203 warning only for varchars or some sort of collections. If I have a numeric (integer, number, ...) output parameter there is no PLW-07203 warning if I omit the NOCOPY clause.

Does anyone know what is special about number type in PL/SQL that there si no PLW-07203 for it?

Comment: Please edit the question and show the relevant code

Comment: I'd *guess* the potential savings for numeric data are much smaller than for strings/collections, because of the way they are [stored internally in a few bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24240516/266304); but I can't see anything to back that up.

Comment: @AlexPoole yea... this is how I think about that too, but also I cannot find any evidence on that....